# Determine gain for a variation of the differential pair

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, gain

In order to prepare for an exam I am trying to solve the following problem: For the circuit shown below (a variation of the differential pair) I want to determine an expression for the gain \$ A_v = V_{out}/V_{in} \$. Backgate effect can be neglected. Furthermore, all transistors can be assumed to be in saturation. I have problems figuring out how to do that.

If I work with the formula for \$ A_v \$ and write
$$
A_v = \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{V_{DD}-R_D I_{DS2}}{V_{in}},
$$
I already do not know how to go on. I cannot say how the current \$ I_B \$ splits up and therefore cannot determine \$ I_{DS2} \$. Can anyone help me out?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffxREF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: what is gm? and where does it go?

Comment: \$ g_m = \frac{\partial I_D}{\partial V_{GS}} \$. What do you mean with where it goes?

Comment: Yes if the average differential Vin-Vb =0 and common mode is biased into saturation then the average output current is shared equally then you can determine your gain from the modulation of Id from Vgs. ie. ignore the DC gain for now and just calculate AC gain